# Vizualizing a bipartite graph with about 500 nodes

Tags: graph, visualization, graphviz, dot

I need to draw a bipartite graph. It has about 500 nodes.

Currently I am trying to do it with graphviz.
The graph has two types of nodes. I want that the first type is on the left side and another nodes on the right side of a plot. If I do plain plot with `dot` then it is a skinny strip of two rows of nodes. These rows are too close to each other, so it is hard to recognize any separate edges between nodes. I tried other layout algorithms like `circo`. I like that nodes are on a circle, but I don't know how to split nodes on right and left semicircles.

The perfect output I would like is next: nodes are spread along a circle but two types of nodes belong to separate hemicircles. I there a way to do it using graph viz?

Would you suggest a better tool, if it is too hard to do in graphviz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the spacing between rows in `dot` using the `ranksep` attribute.  For getting two halves of the graph separated, it might make sense to create two hidden nodes (`style=invis`) with fixed positions, then connect (using `style=invis` edges) each "real" node to the fixed node for its half of the diagram.  You would probably want to use `neato` for this, probably with `overlap=false` as a graph attribute.  Here is a simple example (using non-invisible styles to show how the layout looks):

```cxx
graph test {
  overlap=false; splines=true
  edge [style=dotted, weight=10, len=.2]
  subgraph cluster_left {
    left [pos="-1,0!", color=red /* , style=invis */]
    a -- left
    b -- left
  }
  subgraph cluster_right {
    right [pos="1,0!", color=blue /* , style=invis */]
    c -- right
    d -- right
    e -- right
  }
  edge [style="", weight=1, len=1]
  a -- b
  b -- d
  d -- e
  c -- e
  b -- e
}
```

For a semicircle, setting `weight=1000, len=1` in the first `edge` line and using `fdp` instead of `neato` seems to produce something close (there are still a few nodes that have edge lengths that are slightly off).  You need more nodes to see the effect (I put in extra nodes that are like `b` and `e` but with numeric suffixes on their names for testing).

Comment: I put it in commented out; uncomment that and change "dotted" to "invis" (to hide the edges) for the real version.

Comment: What do you think, is there way to split nodes on a circle using subgraph command?

Comment: There is something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467450/control-layout-using-graphviz-twopi; is that close enough to what you want?

Comment: I am trying to follow your advice, but my left and right nodes does not attract other nodes enough, even though its weight is 10000000. But I don't use cluster, is using cluster essential? I don't like the frame around nodes.

Comment: The cluster part is probably important; you can remove the box around the cluster but I don't remember how off-hand.